# Sagemaker Blazingtext .content_type = 'application/json' AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run a supervised model on Sagemaker using BlazingText model. Here is my code for running the estimator, hyperparameter tuning, deploying to container and model invocation. I am seeing "Attribute Error: cant set attribute".

```
bt = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
role,
instance_count=1,
instance_type='ml.m5.large',
input_mode='File',
output_path=s3_output_location)

bt.set_hyperparameters(mode='supervised')

Code for model tuning
bt.fit(inputs=s3_channels)

Code to deploy to container
customer_entity = bt.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.t2.medium')

Invoking the model
customer_entity.content_type = 'application/json'
response = customer_entity.predict(json.dumps(payload))

Error

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 customer_entity.content_type = 'application/json'
2 response = customer_entity.predict(json.dumps(payload))
3 #response = customer_entity.predict(payload)

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Here from the SageMaker team. You are using SageMaker v2. With v2 you don't directly set content_type instead you set the content type in a Serializer instance. You can either do this in the Predictor's constructor or by setting predictor.serializer afterwards. Note that you can use an already created serializer class that allows you to specify a content_type or alternatively implement a class where you customize it to handle content_type.